# Is there any 2D plotting library compatible with pypy?

Tags: matplotlib, pypy

I am a heavy user of jupyter notebook and, lately, I am running it using pypy instead of python to get extra speed. It works perfectly but I am missing matplotlib so much. Is there any decent 2D plotting library compatible with pypy and jupyter notebook? I don't need fancy stuff, scatter, line and bar plots would be more than enough.

Comment: I have seen screenshots that claim to be running mpl on pypy.  If you are already in the notbook, look at bqplot, altair, and lightning

Comment: They all depend on pandas... I need something without dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html) is working fairly good with pypy. The only problem I have encountered is linked to the use of `numpy.datetime64` that is not yet supported by pypy. Fortunately it is enough to monkey-patch `bokeh/core/properties.py` and `bokeh/util/serialization.py` to pass in case of datetime64 reference.

I did it in this way:

bokeh/core/properties.py

```
...
        try:
            import numpy as np
            datetime_types += (np.datetime64,)
        except:
            pass
...
```

and

bokeh/util/serialization.py

```
...
    # Check for astype failures (putative Numpy < 1.7)
    try:
        dt2001 = np.datetime64('2001')
        legacy_datetime64 = (dt2001.astype('int64') ==
                        dt2001.astype('datetime64[ms]').astype('int64'))
    except:
        legacy_datetime64 = False
        pass
...
```

And managed to get nice looking plots in jupyter using pypy.

Comment: Would you be interested in submitting a PR to make this work on PyPy all the time?